# jenkins Email notification failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i have an issue with email notifier plugin that used to work on my jenkins pipeline.

```
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Invalid command or cannot parse from address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1587)
Caused: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Invalid command or cannot parse from address
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 Invalid command or cannot parse from address

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

> Mailer plugin version 1.20
>
> Jenkins version 2.66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually set a

> from address

with username and domain that will appear as the sender in the emails coming from jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

The error claims to fail at either:

- parsing the "from" address (can break if you have modified email suffix)
- running a command it used to execute.

Maybe recheck plugin's documentation, about what it needs.

Comment: I use an external emailing service that works. what do you mean by the second suggestion "running a command it used to execute."

Comment: I think if you can revisit config and plugin documentation and maybe increase logging level for a short while you may get more info. 
You do not have anything specific about your config published here, so I can only tell you general directions.
Good luck.